# Can't find and pair with a Bluetooth LE device in C++

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

so I wrote a dll that should scan the area and try to pair with a device that has a matching address(it should automatically enter pin "123123" while pairing).An exe calls the dll and tells it the requested address.

Here is dll:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>
#include <iostream>

// Link with the Bthprops.lib file
#pragma comment(lib, "Bthprops.lib")


DWORD WINAPI BluetoothAuthCallbackEx(LPVOID pvParam, PBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_PARAMS pAuthCallbackParams);

// Function to initiate Bluetooth pairing
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int InitiateBluetoothPairing(const char* deviceAddress) {
    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO deviceInfo = { sizeof(deviceInfo) };
    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS searchParams = {
        sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS),
        1,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        15,
        NULL
    };
    HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND btFind = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&searchParams, &deviceInfo);
    if (btFind == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "No devices found." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    BOOL found = FALSE;
    do {
        BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS_STRUCT address;
        memcpy(&address, &deviceInfo.Address, sizeof(address));
        char deviceAddressStr[18]; // Assuming a Bluetooth address string is 17 characters plus null-terminator
        sprintf_s(deviceAddressStr, sizeof(deviceAddressStr), "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
            address.rgBytes[5], address.rgBytes[4], address.rgBytes[3],
            address.rgBytes[2], address.rgBytes[1], address.rgBytes[0]);

        std::cout << "found device Address: " << deviceAddressStr << std::endl;
        if (strcmp(deviceAddress, deviceAddressStr) == 0) {
            found = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    } while (BluetoothFindNextDevice(btFind, &deviceInfo));





    BluetoothFindDeviceClose(btFind);

    if (found) {
        HBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_REGISTRATION hRegHandle = NULL;
        DWORD result = BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx(&deviceInfo, &hRegHandle, (PFN_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_EX)BluetoothAuthCallbackEx, NULL);
        if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to register authentication callback." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        // ... (initiate pairing)
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Device not found." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}


DWORD WINAPI BluetoothAuthCallbackEx(LPVOID pvParam, PBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_PARAMS pAuthCallbackParams) {
    if (pAuthCallbackParams->authenticationMethod == BLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD_LEGACY) {
        BLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATE_RESPONSE response = { 0 };
        response.bthAddressRemote = pAuthCallbackParams->deviceInfo.Address;
        response.authMethod = BLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD_LEGACY;
        response.negativeResponse = FALSE;

        // Convert the PIN code to a multi-byte string
        char pinMultiByte[7];
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, L"123123", -1, pinMultiByte, sizeof(pinMultiByte), NULL, NULL);

        // Ensure that the PIN length does not exceed UCHAR's max value
        size_t pinLength = strlen(pinMultiByte);
        if (pinLength > UCHAR_MAX) {
            std::cerr << "PIN length is too long." << std::endl;
            return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER; // or an appropriate error code
        }

        // Copy the multi-byte PIN code into the response
        memcpy(response.pinInfo.pin, pinMultiByte, pinLength);
        response.pinInfo.pinLength = static_cast<UCHAR>(pinLength);

        BluetoothSendAuthenticationResponseEx(NULL, &response);
    }

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

and here is the exe that calls it:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int InitiateBluetoothPairing(const char* deviceAddress);

int main() {
    std::cout << "Testing DLL function\n";

    int result = InitiateBluetoothPairing("00:18:DA:22:C1:E7");

    std::cout << "Function returned: " << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It just can't find my BLE device even tho other windows and android softwares can easily find it. It finds some other BLE devices when I change "BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS" and I tried many combinations but none worked.
What could be the problem?

BTW this code find that said device perfectly but idk what it's doing different because I'm super noob about this: https://github.com/rohitsangwan01/win_ble/blob/main/BLEServer/BLEServer/BLEServer.cpp

Comment: This API is for Classic Bluetooth only. For LE devices you must use WinRT API.